# Vue Multiselect CSS based on value of select

Tags: vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I am trying to style the multi select of an input based on the value. when i put the condition in vue like the following i am getting the color on all the div including the label
here is my code

```
<custom-select 
  :class="{
    orange : campaignStatus.value ==='ARCHIVED' || campaignStatus.value ==='PAUSED',
    red : campaignStatus.value ==='BANNED' || campaignStatus.value ==='REMOVED'
  }"
  v-model="campaignStatus"
  deselectLabel="Selected"
  label="Status"
  :options="statusOptions" 
  name="status" 
  data-test="campaign-status"
  disabled>
</custom-select>
```

and the result is this: [image]

the goal is to have just the multi-select colored orange like that 
 [image]

the issue is that i dont have the multiselect.multislect_input in my html template so i can i style the multiselect based on its value? for example orange for archived and red for expired?

Comment: Please provide some more information about your css classes and the rendered html code. A jsfiddle with minimal working code would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a class of color in css first. For example:

```
.orange{color:orange}
.red{color:red }
```

And then you can use these classes in vue. Like:

```
:class="{'orange': campaignStatus.value === ARCHIVED , 'red': campaignStatus.value === EXPIRED}"
```

Comment: i am using vuetify so the code i mentioned is working but its working for the entire class and not for multiselect part. i need only for the word "archived"  to be in orange

Comment: You can try with this `campaignStatus.value ===' <span class="orange">ARCHIVED</span>'`

Comment: From where data of selectbox inserting?